# Krull dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

I had the following exercise:

1. Calculate Krull dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$
2. Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. Calculate the dimension of $A[x,x^{-1}]$ as a function of that of $A$.

I have carried out these points using the following theorems:

**Theorem 1.**
Let $K$ be a field. Then dim $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]=n$.

So I deduced dim $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]=2$.

**Theorem 2**
Let $A$ be a noetherian ring. Then dim $A[x_1,\dots, x_n]=$ dim $A+n$.

So I supposed dim $A[x,x^{-1}]=$ dim $A+2$.

---

Now I have found that the results are wrong.
Why couldn't I use these theorems? I don't understand.

And how was I supposed to do the exercise?

How could I calculate  dim $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$ and  dim $A[x,x^{-1}]$?

Comment: You should understand that, in both Theorem 1 and Theorem 2, the variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are supposed to be algebraically independent formal variables. Your $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are however dependent: their product is $1$.

Comment: Oh...Of course...How did I not think about it!

Comment: Is there another way in general you can follow when variables are dependent?

Comment: Do you know the dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x]$? What is the relationship between prime ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and prime ideals of the localization $\mathbb{R}[x][x^{-1}]$? Alternatively, you could consider $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}] \cong \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy-1)$.